# How to map closest integers from two lists in least time?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two very long lists and am trying to map every integer in first list to closet integer in other list within a maximum threshold difference. I can do it looping over entire lists but is there a faster way to do it? Output can be like  `x (of list A ) = y (of list B)` . If a number is equidistant from two integers, any one can be chosen. I tried using -

```
from itertools import product
sorted(product(arr1, arr2), key=lambda t: abs(t[0]-t[1]))
```

which is very slow and also not one to one mapping.

Example:

**Input**

```
A = [1, 3, 8, 77, 66, 25, 40]
B= [2, 5, 12, 120, 30, 21, 40]
Threshold = 40
```

**Output**

1=2 ; 3=5 ; 8=12 ; 77- dropped out as nothing best under threshold; 66=30 (as 40 is closer but has better match in other list ); 25=21; 40=40

Comment: Can you update the question with example input and output?

Comment: @DanhPham added an example

Comment: Why 3=5, not 3=2?

Comment: I would say not, looking at the examples,  but i think one of the lists _could_ be sorted

Comment: Sort both lists and step along them. This reduces O(n^2) to O(n) [O(nlogn) if you include the sorting step]

Comment: Also, how can you have 66=30 with a threshold of 30?

Comment: Please update the example properly, it's creating chaos

Comment: @bhansa  , i'm really sorry. I edited the threshold.

Comment: @MadPhysicist 3=5 and not 3=2 is because 1 is already mapped to 2 and it should be a one-one mapping like i said.

Comment: @Bhushan, what result *would* you expect with a threshold of 30?

Comment: 66 dropped out probably. Because he needs best matches in both lists and is open to dropping outs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in *O(n log n)* using binary search. In Python, you can use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html) module for this.

```
import bisect

A = [1, 3, 8, 77, 66, 25, 40]
B = [2, 5, 12, 120, 30, 21, 40]
threshold = 40

B = sorted(B)  # has to be sorted for binary search

def closest(a, B):
    i = bisect.bisect(B, a)
    b = min(B[max(0, i-1):i+1], key=lambda b: abs(a - b))
    if abs(a - b) < threshold:
        return b

C = {a: closest(a, B) for a in A}
C = {a: b for a, b in C.items() if b is not None}
print(C)  # {1: 2, 66: 40, 3: 2, 40: 40, 8: 5, 25: 21, 77: 40}
```

Now, `C` has the closest element form `B` for each element from `A`, but there might be duplicates (e.g. `40`). To resolve those, we have to do a second pass, sorting the elements from `A` by their "closeness" to any element from `B` using `C`. Then, we can `remove` the elements from `B` once we assigned them to some element from `A`.

```
D = {}
for a in sorted(C, key = lambda a: abs(C[a] - a)):
    b = closest(a, B)
    if b:
        D[a] = b
        B.remove(b)

print(D)  # {1: 2, 66: 30, 3: 5, 8: 12, 40: 40, 25: 21}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `bisect` library, reference at: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bisect.html.

> `bisect.bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=len(a))`
>
> Locate the insertion point for x in a to maintain sorted order.

Example:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

A = [1, 3, 8, 4, 77, 66, 25, 40]
B = [2, 5, 12, 120, 30, 21, 40]
Threshold = 40

B.sort()
for k in A:
    left = bisect_left(B, k)
    right = bisect_right(B, k)

    s = B[left] if abs(B[left] - k) < abs(B[right] - k) else B[right]

    if abs(k - s) <= Threshold:
        print(k, s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can try:

```
print(" ".join(["{}={}".format(i[0],i[1]) for i in list(zip(A,B)) if abs(i[0] - i[1]) <= 30]))
```

output:

```
1=2 3=5 8=12 25=21 40=40
```

Comment: this is not what the question asks. This just prints the pairs that have a difference of less than the threshold. but he wants to find the closest pairs even if they are not at the same index.

Comment: A=[1,55] and B=[56,2] should give 1=2, 55=56